# Error while calling a Post method in Django templates

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am working on an web application using Django. I am trying to access the views in django  using the post method in javascript which is called when a button is clicked

The HTML button which I used in Django templates is

```
<a id = "{{ f.food_id }}" class="btn btn-info" href="#myModal" onclick="addCart(event);" class="trigger-btn" data-toggle="modal">  Add To Cart</a>
```

The above button calls the below java script function

```
<script>
//This function should call the python function (addToCart) in django views.py which is used to add items to the cart
function addCart(event)
{
  var me = event.currentTarget
  var food_id = me.getAttribute("id");
  alert(food_id);

  //The below url "/food/addToCart/(?P<item_id>\d+)" is linked to the addToCart funtion in the views.py

  $.post("/food/addToCart/"+food_id+"/", //This post method isn't working
  {},
  function(data, status){
  });
}
</script>
```

In the above function I'm trying to access the below addToCart method in views.py using the above **post method**

```
def addToCart(request,item_id):
    try:
        cartTrail = Cart.objects.get(user_id=request.user.username,food_id=str(item_id))
        cartTrail.quantity += 1
        cartTrail.save()
        print("already present",cartTrail)
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        items = FoodItem.objects.filter(food_id=item_id)[0]
        cartItem = Cart.objects.create(user_id=request.user.username, 
    res_id=items.restaurant.username.username, 
    food_id=item_id,food_name=items.food_name,price=items.price)
        cartItem.save()
    return JsonResponse({'data':'Added'})
```

My urls.py contains the below url :

```
url(r'^addToCart/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$',views.addToCart,name="addToCart"),
```

**My problem is that the post method isn't working when the addToCart is clicked and due to this** `def addToCart(request,item_id):` **function is not being invoked. Could you please suggest me where I am going wrong**

Comment: Can you share the error log you got when you call post request from js? You may need to send `csrf_token` in your post data.

Comment: @DenizKaplan I'm getting the error stating **SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'post'** in my google chrome inspect console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the csrf_token inside of your post request otherwise it will be rejected by the server here is the piece of [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/)  that talks about that
if you want to workaround the csrf verification you can add this decorator to your view

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def addToCart(request,item_id):
  // the rest of the view
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error stating "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'post' in my google chrome inspect console".

Comment: okey so why are using a post request when you are passing the id within the url, you can change that to get  no ?

Comment: I tried using get but still there is an error saying "TypeError: $.get is not a function"

Comment: try changin $.get to jQuery.get

Comment: thanks for the help !! I was using the SLIM version of the jQuery so it didn't work , <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script> . I changed it to <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> and it is working.